# Unable to create an AWS role in a specific PATH CLI

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, aws-policies, aws-roles

My user has a policy that allows him to **iam:CreateRole** and **iam:DeleteRole** but when I launch this command :

```
aws iam create-role --role-name MyRole --path /projects/ --assume-role-policy-document file://MyRoleTrust.json
```

But I have this error :

```
An error occcured (ValidationError) when calling the CreateRole operation: The specified value for path is invalid.It must begin and end with / and contain only alphanumeric characters and / or / characters.
```

But I have policies using this condition with this type of arn : `"arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/projects/*"`. It means that this /projects/* should exist.

So why do I get this error...I'm a bit confused.
Thanks for you replies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using Windows as your OS. And command line tool is a something like [Git for Windows](https://gitforwindows.org/) with bash emulation.

[Same bug](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/3829) is mentioned in GitHub. The problem is that [mingw trying to be smart, and converting paths](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/24029#issuecomment-250412919)

Here are three possible solutions:

1. Set variable `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1` to disable path conversions
2. <strike>Use escaped `/projects/` parameter by adding extra `/` (`//projects/`)</strike>
3. Remove Windows at all (the best one)

Comment: thx for your reply. The *first tip* doesn't seem working since i get the same error. As for the *second tip*, in AWS console,  i have a role created with this arn : `arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role//projects/MyRole` Is it the right path i was excepting this path : `arn:aws:iam::<account-id>:role/projects/*MyRole` ? I have the impression that there is like an empty folder,no? Regarding the *third tip*, if it wasn't my professionnal laptop i will remove it for sure X)

Comment: how did you use a first tip? it is two possible ways to set variable: 1. run directly in command as prefix: `MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1 aws iam create-role ...`, 2. `export` it widely until bash session is opened: `export MSYS_NO_PATHCONV=1`, and run command then. Are you sure that you set it properly?

Comment: Thx dude it works super fine!! I've to put it on my bashrc directly and not run it directly!